# Most efficient mysql query to retrieve multiple categories for each result in a search listing

Tags: mysql

I have search page that returns 10 articles per page.  Each article can be assigned to multiple categories. As part of the search listing I want to be able to display something like:

```
Title of Article
Added on: 6/11/02
Categories: Basic, Cars, Mustang
Summmary of article
```

The only way I can think of doing it is for each search result do a query that retrieves its categories.  If I do this, though, each search in the app would generate 10+ queries. I also give people the option of listing more than 10 search results, which would generate even more queries.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: `JOIN` the category table(s) on your main query. This will give you a resultset with multiple rows per article (one row per article/category combination). Then you can (a) filter duplicates on your php/asp/ruby/whatever code, or `GROUP BY` category ID and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) the categories on your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thanks! GROUP_CONCAT was exactly what I was looking for.